# Error building opencv 2.4.13.6 with catkin (ROS) workspace

Tags: opencv, ubuntu, build, ros

I want to build my project (in ROS) using opencv 2.4

I installed ros-kinetic version, and opencv3 package (by default, via libopencv-dev ros-kinetic-opencv3 , only opencv3 is available).
For the purpose of my project i need opencv-2.4 version.
I try with several ways (via `CMakelists.txt` of my project etc) to link with my custom built opencv (in `usr/local/include`) but with no success.

My project always links with the installed ros opencv `(/opt/ros/kinetic/include/opencv-3.3.1-dev/opencv2)`

I got the following errors

```
    /usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h:913:7: note: candidate: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>; _Alloc = Eigen::aligned_allocator_indirection<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1> >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>]
       push_back(const value_type& __x)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h:913:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘cv::Point {aka cv::Point_<int>}’ to ‘const value_type& {aka const Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>&}’
/home/user1/user1/catkin_ws/src/rgbd_calibration/src/rgbd_calibration/calibration_test.cpp:1107:79: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>, Eigen::aligned_allocator<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1> > >::push_back(cv::Point)’
           points.push_back(cv::Point(tmp_corners[35].x(), tmp_corners[35].y()));
                                                                               ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/vector:64:0,
                 from /home/user1/user1/catkin_ws/src/calibration_toolkit/calibration_common/include/calibration_common/base/matrix.h:32,
                 from /home/user1/user1/catkin_ws/src/calibration_toolkit/calibration_common/include/calibration_common/base/point_matrix.h:32,
                 from /home/user1/user1/catkin_ws/src/calibration_toolkit/calibration_common/include/calibration_common/objects/globals.h:32,
                 from /home/user1/user1/catkin_ws/src/calibration_toolkit/calibration_common/include/calibration_common/objects/base_object.h:33,
                 from /home/user1/user1/catkin_ws/src/calibration_toolkit/calibration_common/include/calibration_common/objects/sensor.h:21,
                 from /home/user1/user1/catkin_ws/src/calibration_toolkit/calibration_common/include/calibration_common/color/sensor.h:32,
                 from /home/user1/user1/catkin_ws/src/calibration_toolkit/calibration_common/include/calibration_common/pinhole/sensor.h:32,
                 from /home/user1/user1/catkin_ws/src/rgbd_calibration/include/rgbd_calibration/calibration_test.h:21,
                 from /home/user1/user1/catkin_ws/src/rgbd_calibration/src/rgbd_calibration/calibration_test.cpp:18:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h:913:7: note: candidate: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>; _Alloc = Eigen::aligned_allocator_indirection<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1> >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>]
       push_back(const value_type& __x)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h:913:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘cv::Point {aka cv::Point_<int>}’ to ‘const value_type& {aka const Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>&}’
/home/user1/user1/catkin_ws/src/rgbd_calibration/src/rgbd_calibration/calibration_test.cpp:1108:79: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>, Eigen::aligned_allocator<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1> > >::push_back(cv::Point)’
           points.push_back(cv::Point(tmp_corners[30].x(), tmp_corners[30].y()));
                                                                               ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/vector:64:0,
                 from /home/user1/user1/catkin_ws/src/calibration_toolkit/calibration_common/include/calibration_common/base/matrix.h:32,
                 from /home/user1/user1/catkin_ws/src/calibration_toolkit/calibration_common/include/calibration_common/base/point_matrix.h:32,
                 from /home/user1/user1/catkin_ws/src/calibration_toolkit/calibration_common/include/calibration_common/objects/globals.h:32,
                 from /home/user1/user1/catkin_ws/src/calibration_toolkit/calibration_common/include/calibration_common/objects/base_object.h:33,
                 from /home/user1/user1/catkin_ws/src/calibration_toolkit/calibration_common/include/calibration_common/objects/sensor.h:21,
                 from /home/user1/user1/catkin_ws/src/calibration_toolkit/calibration_common/include/calibration_common/color/sensor.h:32,
                 from /home/user1/user1/catkin_ws/src/calibration_toolkit/calibration_common/include/calibration_common/pinhole/sensor.h:32,
                 from /home/user1/user1/catkin_ws/src/rgbd_calibration/include/rgbd_calibration/calibration_test.h:21,
                 from /home/user1/user1/catkin_ws/src/rgbd_calibration/src/rgbd_calibration/calibration_test.cpp:18:
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h:913:7: note: candidate: void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [with _Tp = Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>; _Alloc = Eigen::aligned_allocator_indirection<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1> >; std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::value_type = Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>]
       push_back(const value_type& __x)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/5/bits/stl_vector.h:913:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘cv::Point {aka cv::Point_<int>}’ to ‘const value_type& {aka const Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>&}’
/home/user1/user1/catkin_ws/src/rgbd_calibration/src/rgbd_calibration/calibration_test.cpp:1110:113: error: no matching function for call to ‘fillConvexPoly(cv::Mat&, std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>, Eigen::aligned_allocator<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1> > >&, cv::Scalar)’
           cv::fillConvexPoly(tmp_image, points, cv::Scalar(c == 0 ? 128 : 0, c == 1 ? 128 : 0, c == 2 ? 128 : 0));
                                                                                                                 ^
In file included from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/opencv-3.3.1-dev/opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp:48:0,
                 from /opt/ros/kinetic/include/image_geometry/pinhole_camera_model.h:6,
                 from /home/user1/user1/catkin_ws/src/calibration_toolkit/calibration_common/include/calibration_common/pinhole/camera_model.h:32,
                 from /home/user1/user1/catkin_ws/src/calibration_toolkit/calibration_common/include/calibration_common/pinhole/sensor.h:33,
                 from /home/user1/user1/catkin_ws/src/rgbd_calibration/include/rgbd_calibration/calibration_test.h:21,
                 from /home/user1/user1/catkin_ws/src/rgbd_calibration/src/rgbd_calibration/calibration_test.cpp:18:
/opt/ros/kinetic/include/opencv-3.3.1-dev/opencv2/imgproc.hpp:4452:17: note: candidate: void cv::fillConvexPoly(cv::Mat&, const Point*, int, const Scalar&, int, int)
 CV_EXPORTS void fillConvexPoly(Mat& img, const Point* pts, int npts,
                 ^
/opt/ros/kinetic/include/opencv-3.3.1-dev/opencv2/imgproc.hpp:4452:17: note:   candidate expects 6 arguments, 3 provided
/opt/ros/kinetic/include/opencv-3.3.1-dev/opencv2/imgproc.hpp:4469:19: note: candidate: void cv::fillConvexPoly(cv::InputOutputArray, cv::InputArray, const Scalar&, int, int)
 CV_EXPORTS_W void fillConvexPoly(InputOutputArray img, InputArray points,
                   ^
/opt/ros/kinetic/include/opencv-3.3.1-dev/opencv2/imgproc.hpp:4469:19: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘std::vector<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1>, Eigen::aligned_allocator<Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 1> > >’ to ‘cv::InputArray {aka const cv::_InputArray&}’
rgbd_calibration/CMakeFiles/test_calibration.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'rgbd_calibration/CMakeFiles/test_calibration.dir/src/rgbd_calibration/test_node.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [rgbd_calibration/CMakeFiles/test_calibration.dir/src/rgbd_calibration/test_node.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
rgbd_calibration/CMakeFiles/test_calibration.dir/build.make:86: recipe for target 'rgbd_calibration/CMakeFiles/test_calibration.dir/src/rgbd_calibration/calibration_test.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [rgbd_calibration/CMakeFiles/test_calibration.dir/src/rgbd_calibration/calibration_test.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3448: recipe for target 'rgbd_calibration/CMakeFiles/test_calibration.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [rgbd_calibration/CMakeFiles/test_calibration.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 98%] Linking CXX executable /home/user1/user1/catkin_ws/devel/lib/rgbd_calibration/rgbd_offline_calibration
[ 98%] Built target rgbd_offline_calibration
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
```

I tried several things, like inserting `find_package(OpenCV 2.4.12 REQUIRED
   NO_MODULE #Should be optional, tells CMake to use config mode
   PATHS /usr/local # Tells CMake to look here
   NO_DEFAULT_PATH #and don't look anywhere else
)`
 in `CMakeLists.txt` of the project but still the same issue.

Is there a safe way to explicitly link with my custom built opencv?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possible answers to your problem.
Firstly, run `pkg-config --modversion opencv`, to make sure that the version you are asking for exists.
Then you could try to do the following:

1) In your CMakeLists.txt: `find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED PATHS path/to/opencv/opencv/opencv-2.4.12/cmake)`

2) In the beginning of the same file, add the following:

```
set(OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS
  /usr/local/include
  /usr/local/include/opencv2
)

set(OpenCV_LIB_DIR
  /usr/local/lib
)
```

3) Before running the catkin build, run

```
export CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/usr/local:$CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

4) Beware! Everytime before running `catkin build`, always perform `catkin clean`.
There is always the chance of not deleting previous configuration and not being able to detect the new OpenCV version that you ask for.

One of them, or a combination of them may work.